# I need datasheet for a 4 pin optocoupler marked 817C E172H

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, opto-isolator

It is used in an automotive vehicle power conversion board. I am trying to service the board but I don't know the exact manufacturer. I have added the IC image. Its dimensions are 6.7mm X 4.7mm X 3.3mm.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! If you can't find the datasheet for that particular one, look for any 817 optocoupler. They should all have the same pinout and function but CTR differs.

Comment: PC817 is quite common. You can find its datasheet everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the component, It belongs to Qunxin Microelectronics- [Photo Transistor](https://www.qxmicro.com/upfiles/products/202304/ADBRPJJ065BX.pdf)

[image]